# Haskell profiling -prof

Tags: haskell

again...

I'm messing around with profiling in GHC after recently starting to learn Haskell. I'm trying to use profiling to see how different implementations of functions vary in performance, for example using list comprehension instead of map. I'm trying to compile with the -prof flag but im getting the following output:

```
david@david-LinuxMint ~/Desktop/Sandbox/Haskell/a $ ghc --make Filt -prof

Filt.hs:1:1:
    Could not find module `Prelude'
    Perhaps you haven't installed the profiling libraries for package `base'?
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for
```

The program compiles fine with the -prof flag omitted. Anybody have any ideas where im going wrong? I've tried to find something on SO/internet but my Google-Fu is failing me? Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for Linux, Debian in particular, but I believe the OP is using Mint which I think might be a Debian variant.

You probably got base from the OS packaging system (Debian: APT), so you'll also want to get the profiling version of base from that same system.  On Debian the hackage package "foo" is in the Debian package "libghc-foo-dev"[1].  The profiling version of "libghc-blah-dev" is in the Debian package "libghc-blah-prof".

Now, base is a little special.  Those packages exist, but are "virtual"; they are listed in relationships, but are actually installed by (one or more) other real packages.  In Debian virtual libghc-base-dev is provided by real package ghc and virtual libghc-base-dev is provided by real package ghc-prof.

So, install ghc-prof (or the Mint equivalent) and you'll be good, or at least move on the the next error.

Eventually, you'll end up downloading and building packages directly from hackage.  You'll have to change your cabal settings to build the profiling versions of those libraries.

[1] If another Haskell compiler gets (back) into Debian, the "ghc" in "libghc" will change to a string suitable for that compiler.